# Why can "yea' and "nay" be used interchangeably here?

Tags: etymology

The definitions of Yea and Nay, provided by Lexico, are:

[Yea](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yea);

> Used to emphasize a more appropriate word than one just used.
>
> ‘he was full, yea, crammed with anxieties’

and [Nay](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nay)

> Or rather (used to emphasize a more appropriate word than one just used)
>
> ‘permission to build the superstore will take months, nay years’

What, if any, are the historical reasons as to why 'Yea' and 'Nay' are semantically identical with regard to the context of introducing 'a more appropriate word than the one just used'?

Did their meanings arise independently of one another?

Is my interpretation that they're semantically identical, incorrect? Do they in fact have slightly different connotations when used in this context?

Comment: Yea agrees with the preceding word or words, and substitutes something better; nay disagrees with the preceding word or words, and substitutes something better.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Wouldn't both 'Yea' and 'Nay' disagree with the preceding word? In the ‘Yea’ example, 'full' implies complete capacity, whereas 'crammed' implies 'completely fill[ed] (a place or container) to the point of overflowing.'. Similarly, in the ‘Nay’ example, 'months' implies 2 or more months, whereas 'years' implies 2 or more years (24 or more months). In both instances the former word is an underestimate, the latter a better approximation.  Thus, both ‘Yea’ and ‘Nay disagree with their respective preceding word, and could theoretically be used interchangeably in eachothers examples.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Conversely, Couldn’t ‘Yea’ and ‘Nay’ be interpreted to agree with their respective preceding word. The preceding word in both instances is a conservative approximation, which is still logically correct, even if ‘Nay’ or ‘Yea’ (and the succeeding word) was absent. Since ‘years’ are just a collection of ‘months’, and the state of being ‘crammed’ requiring a state of being ‘full’, the use of ‘Yea’ and ‘Nay; could be interpreted as agreeing with the former conservative approximation and affirming a more accurate one.